# What Japanese word for "user experience" or UX in IT field?

Tags: translation, words

My team is developing a app for mobile.
I want to tell to customer about the speed of some APIs are very slow. So it is not good for **User Experience** (UX)
How to say it in Japanese?

Comment: Sorry, we don't do translations on this site.

Comment: It's worth noting that if the customer is familiar with software development, they may already know the abbreviation UX, since it does get used that way in Japanese in the context of software development.

Comment: As my comment on dungarian's answer indicates, I agree with jogloran that this is essentially a translation request. In fact, it is one that could easily be answered by consulting a good English-Japanese or monolingual Japanese dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're asking here, because UX is not a simple "word" in the dictionary. There currently is no Japanese word equivalent with such context. Thus, UX is called "UX" in Japanese. You may want to say "User Experience" when verbally communicating.

This is interesting, because the mobility industry has created 乗り心地  (passenger comfort), a beautiful word to express their UX. But despite developing great video games and electronic applications for long, Japan still has not developed their own word to express UX.

But this may not be the case in future:

---

"API is slow" is technically wrong, as the slowness is caused by connection, middleware, etc.

- "API" is API.
- "Middleware" is middleware.
- "Connection" is 回線 (as in the "internet connection").

Japanese word for 回線 exists, because we have been using (telephone) connections for a long time. So in the future, there might be new Japanese word to represent "UX".

---

Although there is no perfect match for the word, in essence it may be described as:

- 使い心地

or/and

- 使い勝手

These words are common enough that you may research on your own. Tech savvy people may say "UX is different from 使い心地・使い勝手" which is true, but I consider it close enough. After all, when someone asks "what does UX mean?" those are the words we tend to use for explanation.

---

**EDIT**

For further research or rationale, I recommend to consult the appropriate source, which is not a dictionary but an industry standard public specification/standards - JIS Z 8521 or 8531. This is because UX is still somewhere between a word and a term. There are many terms like UX causing the same debate: Robust design is 堅牢設計 or ロバストデザイン? Ergonomics is 人間工学 or エルゴノミクス? It's an interesting subject.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "there is no Japanese word equivalent." The fourth edition of 『大辞林』 **does** have an entry for UX in the 「アルファベット・その他」section. It refers one to the term ユーザ・エクスペリエンス, which is defined in the main body of the dictionary as 「製品やサーボスを利用したときに得られる知識・気分・感覚などの総体。ユーザー体験。」If these terms (UX, ユーザ・エクスペリエンス, and ユーザー体験) are used and understood by at least some native Japanese speakers, and are included in a widely available monolingual dictionary, then it seems to me that they are in fact Japanese, even though they contain elements that are derived from English.

Comment: @Nanigashi I understand what you mean. You seem to believe the question was a simple translation request of a ubiquitous word. I interpreted the question in a quite different way, and believe it deserved an answer, so I gave it my best shot. Your comment is a potentially helpful and concise answer, so I'd post it as an answer if I were you. You're always free to flag or down vote if you believe this question in itself is wrong. Again from my perspective サーボス isn't even a legit word, but I won't dare challenge a dictionary.

Comment: 「サーボス」 is just a transcription error. The Daijirin entry says 「サービス」.

Comment: So sorry about that typo! As Darius Jahandarie points out, the entry does of course say サービス; I apologize for not checking my transcription more carefully before posting the comment. And I have already downvoted and flagged the question. (Though I have not downvoted your answer, which I'm sure the OP will find helpful and informative.) And no, I don't think these terms are "ubiquitous" at all -- hence "used and understood by **at least some** native Japanese speakers."

Answer (score 4):

For my day job in software engineering (game development), I often give technical presentations, and have technical meetings with different types of audiences. Discussing UX is something I do very commonly.

To express the concept of UX, I find ユーザー エクスペリエンス a bit unwieldy, and often unknown to less savvy audiences, so I generally use ユーザー体験 instead, as it's easy to understand, easy to read, and fits better in a presentation slide.